# bash getopts doesnt see flags after first argument

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to handle flags after the first argument in my bash script, but getopts only returns the flags before the argument.

```
or flag in getopts; do
    case $flag in
        d)
            echo "-d flag was triggered!" >&2
            ;;
        \?)
            echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
            ;;
    esac
done
```

and when I run it, I'd like in this example for the "flag was triggered!" string to print three times rather than once.

```
$ ./myscript.sh -d arg1 -d -d -d
getopts
-d (develop mode) was triggered!
```

Comment: does your environment have POSIXLY_CORRECT defined? if so, it will ignore everything after the first non-option argument.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this tutorial on GetOpt. in this case it looks like you have neglected your opstring

try somthing like:

```
for flag in getopts "M:d:a"; do
    case $flag in
...
```

which means you expect possible valid options of -d -M and -a. the : indicates that the -d and a options takes a parameter (: goes before the option in question), so you could invoke it like

```
./somescript -M -d sometext -a somemoretext
```

also don't use duplicate options. it will have unpredictable results on differant systems and shells.

http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial

Comment: I read that tutorial before posting. It's definitely a good intro, but it doesn't handle the case I was trying to solve, which required some non-flagged first argument: `./somescript arg1 -M -d sometext -a somemoretext`. As you guessed in your comment on my question, the POSIXLY_CORRECT environment variable was my issue. Rather than unsetting it, I just worked around the whole mess it by iterating through "$@" instead of using getopts.